BQSkit Selecting Starting Circuit Structure
Background
On the BQSKit repository, there is a nice example of using the qfactor algorithm to instantiate a 3-qubit Toffoli circuit. For this to work, however, it is first necessary to specify an initial circuit structure consisting of variable unitary gates that can then be parametrically tuned to the target (Toffoli). I include the example below
"""
Numerical Instantiation is the foundation of many of BQSKit's algorithms.

This example demonstrates building a circuit template that can implement the
toffoli gate and then instantiating it to be the gate.
"""
from __future__ import annotations

import numpy as np

from bqskit.ir.circuit import Circuit
from bqskit.ir.gates import VariableUnitaryGate
from bqskit.qis.unitary import UnitaryMatrix

# We will optimize towards the toffoli unitary.
toffoli = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
])
toffoli = UnitaryMatrix(toffoli)

# Start with the circuit structure
circuit = Circuit(3)
circuit.append_gate(VariableUnitaryGate(2), [1, 2])
circuit.append_gate(VariableUnitaryGate(2), [0, 2])
circuit.append_gate(VariableUnitaryGate(2), [1, 2])
circuit.append_gate(VariableUnitaryGate(2), [0, 2])
circuit.append_gate(VariableUnitaryGate(2), [0, 1])

# Instantiate the circuit template with qfactor
circuit.instantiate(
    toffoli,
    method='qfactor',
    diff_tol_a=1e-12,   # Stopping criteria for distance change
    diff_tol_r=1e-6,    # Relative criteria for distance change
    dist_tol=1e-12,     # Stopping criteria for distance
    max_iters=100000,   # Maximum number of iterations
    min_iters=1000,     # Minimum number of iterations
    slowdown_factor=0,   # Larger numbers slowdown optimization
    # to avoid local minima
)

# Calculate and print final distance
dist = circuit.get_unitary().get_distance_from(toffoli, 1)
print('Final Distance: ', dist)

# You can use synthesis to convert the `VariableUnitaryGate`s to
# native gates. Alternatively, you can build a circuit directly out of
# native gates and use the default instantiater to instantiate directly.

Question
How do I select an initial circuit structure for an arbitrary circuit to instantiate? If for example instead of the Toffoli gate I wanted to implement a full adder I would replace the Toffoli matrix with one corresponding to the full adder's operation but what would be the starting structure for the VariableUnitaryGates?
For the Toffoli it is as follows:
# Start with the circuit structure
circuit = Circuit(3)
circuit.append_gate(VariableUnitaryGate(2), [1, 2])
circuit.append_gate(VariableUnitaryGate(2), [0, 2])
circuit.append_gate(VariableUnitaryGate(2), [1, 2])
circuit.append_gate(VariableUnitaryGate(2), [0, 2])
circuit.append_gate(VariableUnitaryGate(2), [0, 1])

What would it be for a full adder or any arbitrary circuit?
